# android: different textvies and edittexts depending on radiobuttons

Tags: android, textview, radio-button, textedit

I'm starting to learn a bit about android programming and watch plenty of guides/tutorials but there's one question none of the guides answer. I have a radio group of two buttons, simply like this(in the xml):

```
    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radioButton1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:checked="true"
        android:text="button1" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radioButton2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="button2" />
</RadioGroup>
```

The thing is that i want to show different textviews and different edittexts depending on what radio button is clicked, does anybody know where i can find a good example about this or might even wanna make an example yourself?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can simply wrap your textview's of type1 with some parent View like LinearLayout and so on for the other textview's types.
Than simply onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup arg0, int checkedId) show and hide the wrappers views.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do it is to just add everything to your main view.  Then, depending on which is clicked, set the visibility of all the items you don't want to see to View.GONE, and those you do to View.INVISIBLE.  Or if you have something more complex and the two views don't share a lot of variables, implementing them as fragments may make sense.